# can't get javascript function to execute

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with Javascript and can't get the code below to work. When I click the button, nothing happens. Could someone point out what I did wrong? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sarah's Puppy Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input">
        <input id="puppyNumber" size=30>
        <button onClick="doLoop()"> Get your puppies </button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/html">
        function doLoop() {
        var number = document.getElementById('puppyNumber').value;
            var puppy = [];
            while (var i = 0; i < parseInt(number); i++) {
                puppy = puppy.push('puppy<br>');
            }
            alert(puppy);


        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: an alert box to popup with the word puppy printed the number of times i entered into the input

Comment: Things you can try when "nothing happens": 1) Check your browser's JavaScript error log 2) Add `alert` statements to get a glimpse of what's happening.

Comment: did you check the error log of browser?is the function not firing at all???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of...

```
puppy = puppy.push('puppy<br>');
```

...just say...

```
puppy.push('puppy<br>');
```

`push` returns the element that was pushed, not the array to which it was pushed.

Your code will cause the variable `puppy` to be set to the string `"puppy<br>"`.  Then you'll try to do `"puppy<br>".push("puppy<br>")`, which is obviously invalid.

Comment: Michael's answer is the more complete answer here, and I have marked it as such.

Comment: you guys are awesome thanks so much! is there a reason to use the for rather than while loop in general in javascript?

Comment: You can use a while loop, but the syntax for while loops is different.  You would need to do `while(i < number) { puppy.push(str); i++ }`

Answer (score 5):

Three problems I see.

1. First, use `text/javascript` for the `<script type='text/javascript'>`
2. Second, change `while` to `for` in your loop.  A `while` loop is for testing against a condition, but you have setup a counter.
3. Thrid, don't assign `puppy` with the `push()` method.  `.push()` acts directly on the array.

[Here's the corrected version in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/xqQhN/)

```
<!-- type="text/javascript" not "text/html" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doLoop() {
    var number = document.getElementById('puppyNumber').value;
        var puppy = [];

        // This is a for loop, rather than a while loop
        // Also for good measure, use the second param to parseInt() for a
        // decimal radix to avoid getting binary or octal numbers accidentally.
        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(number, 10); i++) {
            // Don't assign the result back to puppy
            puppy.push('puppy<br>');
        }
        alert(puppy);


    }
</script>
```